# How do I highlight words starting with a dollar sign in Draft.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm trying to change the font colour for words starting with a dollar sign ($). I believe this should be possible in Draft.js as both stocktwits and twitter appear to use this library and changing of font colour for tickers (stocktwits) and hashtags (twitter) is done on these sites. After playing around with Draft.js and lots of googling I can't figure out a way to do it. Has anyone done anything similar?